# How do I make a voting poll in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I would like to make a voting poll in AppleScript, I would like to customize the values and I would like the system to tally the results and email the final result to me at: dirtbikeflyboy917@gmail.com.

Please reply ASAP!

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't asking a specific question. It sounds more like you're asking someone to write a program for you. Please specify what specific things are giving you trouble. As a start, do you actually know AppleScript?

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure the vote count per candidate is incremented by **one** per vote!

Comment: @Geoff: No Chicago-style voting? (Vote early, vote often...)

Comment: it's pretty simple, just make an app to let me make a voting app.  my question is how do I make it?  What code is needed to do this?

Comment: @Telemachus: I was thinking the antithesis of Presidential-election-style voting. :)

@Ben: Rather than reinventing the wheel, you could try using an existing AppleScript interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

Alas, you don't describe your requirements in nearly enough detail to get useful advice. (Web-based? Desktop-based? To run on one machine, or on many? For public or private use? Does it need to be secure? What information does it need to display to users? Etc.)

BTW, there are plenty of [free online poll creators](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+online+poll+creator) available; have you investigated any of those?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this rather than in Applescript.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Let's suggest other languages that the OP doesn't know. Then he can post a question asking how to do it in _those_ languages. After all, as he points out, "it's pretty simple." He just needs to know "What code is needed to do this?"

Comment: NEVERMIND!  I DONT Need it anymore!